# Adding and deleting millions of records daily

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition.  My table has 30 days worth of data.  Each day consists of 12 million records.  Each day, I need to import 12 million new records and delete the 12 million oldest records.  The table has two indexes and no keys. I am using BCP to import the new data.  This takes between .5 and 2.5 hours to run.  I am deleting in batches.  The delete takes 20+ hours.  Dropping and recreating indexes did not seem to help.  What is the fastest solution?

```
    col1 varchar(10)
    col2 varchar(10)
    col3 int
    col4 date

    index1 (col1, col2, col4)
    index2 (col4)
```

Comment: I am using web edition which I don't think support partitions.

Comment: I would take a look at your [memory, CPU, and disk overhead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190994(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> Update: This won't work with Web Edition but since it is here, I think I will leave it here. It can be useful for others.

One way to simulate partition would be to create and truncate daily tables while using union all in a view.

It will probably help to add several fast SSD and use it especially for log files and tempdb.

> Partition approch

The goal is to reduce the amount of transaction log by only updating metadata.

When data is move or remove from a partition, it Insert and Delete rows which will result in (tons of) `LOB_INSERT_ROWS` and `LOB_DELETE_ROW` in the transaction logs.

The only option would be to truncate the partition but this option does not exist.
We can avoid it by only using `Merge` and `Split` on empty Partitions.

In the sample below, I will keep things shorter and only create data for the past 3 months (ie. August, September and October) but you can easily expand it to X months or X days. August will be removed once data starts being added to November and so on with September and December...

> File and Filegroup

I first create 6 files and file groups [Part_0] to [Part_5]:

```
Alter Database [Test] Add Filegroup [Part_0];
...
Alter Database [Test] Add Filegroup [Part_5];
Alter Database [Test] Add File( NAME = N'Part_0', FILENAME = N'...\Part_0.ndf' , SIZE = 100MB , FILEGROWTH = 100MB ) TO Filegroup [Part_0];
...
Alter Database [Test] Add File( NAME = N'Part_5', FILENAME = N'...\Part_5.ndf' , SIZE = 100MB , FILEGROWTH = 100MB ) TO Filegroup [Part_5];
```

> Function and Scheme

```
Create Partition Function [DateKeyPartFunction] (datetime2)
as Range Right For Values ('20150801', '20150901', '20151001', '20151101', '20151201');
Create Partition Scheme [DateKeyPartScheme] as Partition [DateKeyPartFunction]
To ([Part_0], [Part_1], [Part_2], [Part_3], [Part_4], [Part_5]);
```

Again there are 6 partitions. This will be explained later but this is mostly due to the need to have empty partitions.

> Table

Because I don't know the exact design of your table, I will be working with this table:

```
Create Table dbo.DataPart(id int identity(0, 1), name char(1000), name_date datetime2);
```

and this `Clustered Index`:

```
Create Clustered Index IDX_Part On dbo.DataPart(name_date) On DateKeyPartScheme(name_date);
```

> Dummy data

This code creates over a million record in a range of dummy dates every 6 seconds from October to August(now):

```
With inc(n) as(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1))-1 From (
        Select 1 From (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x3(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x4(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x5(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x6(n)
    ) as x(n)
)
Insert into dbo.DataPart(name, name_date) 
Select TOP(1000000) '', DATEADD(second, -n*6, getdate()) From inc;
```

> Partitioned Data:

This will partionned as follow:

```
Id Partition    Left Bound      Right Bound     Row Count
1  [Part_0]                 < '20150801'    0
2  [Part_1] >= '20150801'   < '20150901'    184042
3  [Part_2] >= '20150901'   < '20151001'    432000
4  [Part_3] >= '20151001'   < '20151101'    383958
5  [Part_4] >= '20151101'   < '20151201'    0
6  [Part_5] >= '20151201'                   0
```

- [Part_1], [Part_2], [Part_3] contain data for August, September and October.
- [Part_0] (ie. <'20150801') only exists because it needs an empty partition before we can empty [Part_1] (August) once in November. It would be data for July and before but must remain empty.
- It make things easier to already have an empty partition for next month although it will remain empty until it reach November. This is the purpose of [Part_4] for November.
- Partition Scheme needs an extra partition for everything outside of the right boundary. This is [Part_5] for December and beyond and it must remain empty as well.

> November

Once in November, new rows will go to [Part_4] and August data can be removed from [Part_1].
The only way to remove it without having to delete hundred of thousands of rows is to move [Part_1] away from the table:

```
Create Table dbo.DataPart_Temp(id int identity(0, 1), name char(1000), name_date datetime2);
Create Clustered Index IDX_Part_temp On dbo.DataPart_temp(name_date) On [Part_1];
Alter Table DataPart Switch Partition 2 to DataPart_temp Partition 1;
```

- `DataPart_Temp` must be identical to `DataPart` (columns, indexes)
- Because [Part_1] is move from `DataPart` to `DataPart_temp`, the clustered index on `DataPart_temp` must be created on the same filegroup: [Part_1]
- [Part_1] is the second partition of `DataPart` and is switch  to the first and only Partition of `DataPart_temp`. All August rows are now in `DataPart_temp`.

the table is now partitioned as follow:

```
id Partition    Left Bound      Right Bound     Row Count
1  [Part_0]                 < '20150801'    0
2  [Part_1] >= '20150801'   < '20150901'    0
3  [Part_2] >= '20150901'   < '20151001'    432000
4  [Part_3] >= '20151001'   < '20151101'    383958
5  [Part_4] >= '20151101'   < '20151201'    0
6  [Part_5] >= '20151201'                   0
```

> Merge

[Part_0] and [Part_1] are now empty and can be merge:

```
Alter Partition Function [DateKeyPartFunction]() Merge Range ('20150801');
```

[Part_1] has been removed:

```
id Partition    Left Bound      Right Bound     Row Count
1  [Part_0]                 < '20150901'    0
2  [Part_2] >= '20150901'   < '20151001'    432000
3  [Part_3] >= '20151001'   < '20151101'    383958
4  [Part_4] >= '20151101'   < '20151201'    0
5  [Part_5] >= '20151201'                   0
```

> Add Next month

Now that [Part_1] is not used anymore, it can be added to the Partition Scheme as the next available partition:

```
Alter Partition Scheme [DateKeyPartScheme] Next Used [Part_1];
```

And then [Part_5] (December, >= '20151201') can be splited:

```
Alter Partition Function [DateKeyPartFunction]() Split Range ('20160101');
```

Since [Part_5] is empty, nothing has to be move. The other half of [Part_5] will go to the next available partition which is [Part_1]:

```
Id Partition    Left Bound      Right Bound     Row Count
1  [Part_0]                 < '20150901'    0
2  [Part_2] >= '20150901'   < '20151001'    432000
3  [Part_3] >= '20151001'   < '20151101'    383958
4  [Part_4] >= '20151101'   < '20151201'    x rows in November
5  [Part_5] >= '20151201'   < '20160101'    0
6  [Part_1] >= '20160101'                   0
```

> Clean Up

`DataPart_temp` can now be truncated and then dropped (or at least drop its Clustered Index).

> Following months

In December, Partition ID 2 must be move away ([Part_2]), merged with partition 1 and then added back before January split.

In order to automate this process, you will have to look for the name of the filegroup for Partition 2:

And then create dynamic SQL to:

- Add Clustered Index to DataPart_temp on [Part_X] (similar to DataPart)
- Switch [Part_X] from DataPart to DataPart_temp
- Merge Partition 1 and 2
- Add [Part_X] to DataPart
- Split the last partition
- Truncate DataPart_temp
- Drop DataPart_temp or its Clustered Index

If you use fn_dblog, you should see that transaction logs are minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Web edition is probably the wrong SKU to be using for the type of operation you are doing. Is this some kind of data warehouse solution? Partitions would be the right approach from a solution view, however since that is not doable, one approach is to have two copies of the table - one with current data, and one with the latest data.  If you are accessing the table directly, then rename the tables appropriately when you are ready to switch over.  If you are accessing the table through some stored procs, then simply alter the procs so they point to the new table.  This can all be easily automated.

When you are ready for next day's operation, you can begin prepping the table - bcp out the data you need, then bcp it back in, then bcp in the new data.  No delete needed.  Why it takes up to 2.5 hrs to bcp-in - do you have an understanding why?  I am willing to betting it is due to disk IO being bottleneck.  That and/or your data/log files are autogrowing.  When prepping the new table, you can alleviate some of it by setting the recovery model appropriately (bulk-log, or simple), then setting it back after bulk operations are complete.